# Help with regex - email address matching

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have the following regex which suppose to match email addresses:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\-/=?^_`{|}~][a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\-/=?^_`{|}~.]{0,63}@[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*[a-z0-9](\\.[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*[a-z0-9])+$.
```

I have the following code in AS3:

```
var mails:Array = str.toLowerCase().match(pattern);
```

(pattern is RegExp with the mentioned regular expression).

I retrieve two results, when `str` is `gaga@example.com`:

1. `gaga@example.com`
2. `.com`

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.com` was captured by the last part of the regex `(\\.[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*[a-z0-9])`.

Regular expressions [capture substrings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) matched by portions of the pattern that are enclosed in `()` for later use.

For example, the regex `0x([0-9a-fA-F])` will match a hexadecimal number of the form 0x9F34 and capture the hex portion in a separate group.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your regex, there is a good tutorial about email validation [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

To me this reads:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_{|}~]           # single of chosen character set
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\-/=?^_{|}~.]{0,63}   # any of chosen character set with the addition of , \
@
[a-z0-9]                              # single alpha numeric
[a-z0-9\-]*                           # any alphanumeric with the addition of -
a-z                                   # single alphabetical
0-9+                                  # at least one number
$                                     # end of line
.                                     # any character
```

As to why you get two sub-strings in your array, its because both match the pattern - [see docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/String.html#match())

Comment: Now my answer looks a bit daft as the regex in the question has been changed...  This is what it was before honest! :)

Answer (score 1):

`gaga@example.com` is the match of the whole regular expression and `.com` is the last match of the first group (`(\\.[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\-]*[a-z0-9])`).

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\-/=?^_`{|}~][a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\-/=?^_`{|}~.]{0,63}@[a-z0-9\\-]*[a-z0-9]+\\.([a-z0-9\\-]*[a-z0-9]))+$
```

This seem to work as expected (tested in Regex Tester). Last capturing group removed.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have said:

There are two results because it matches both the whole email address, and the last group surrounded by parentheses.

If you don't want a group to be captured you can add `?:` to the beginning of the group. Look in the AS documentation for non-capturing groups:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=00000118.html#wp129703

"A noncapturing group is one that is used for grouping only; it is not "collected," and it does not match numbered backreferences. Use (?: and ) to define noncapturing groups, as follows:

`var pattern = /(?:com|org|net)/;`"